# How can I get barcode-scan information into my photo metadata, onsite, untethered?

Tags: metadata, event-photography

I need a DSLR camera with a barcode scanner for on-site tours photography, which means it needs to be untethered! The image would have to contain the barcode scanned information in the image metadata or in the name itself.

I've seen solutions like, Foolography and a $2600 Canon Studio Edition launched in 2010. But I'm not sure of either those products!

So I'm asking the gurus here how I can get this working, which camera would I need and any accessory necessary?

I'm trying to recreate something like I saw the on-site volume photographers do in Disney's parks.

Comment: Do you mean that when you take a photo with the DLSR that the camera decodes the barcode and transfers that information to the meta-data of the image?

Comment: Not at the same time, I first read the barcode and the next pictures I take will contains the informatio!

Comment: That sounds like you'd need a DSLR with custom firmware.  I have no idea if what you want is possible (so I'll leave this as a comment) but perhaps you should take a look at http://www.magiclantern.fm/index.html and/or ask people there.

Comment: Thanks @PeterM! I'll take a deep look at MaginLantern!
FTR. I saw it working in real life twice! Not sure if it was the same company, didn't seem to be!
The first was in Atlanta Acuarium by www.sharpshooterimaging.com, and the second was as i mentioned in Disney parks. (www.MyDisneyPhotoPass.com)

Comment: You might be better off simply snapping a shot of the barcode when you'd scan it, using software to read it and applying the information to every image up to the next one containing a barcode.  All of that happens after the fact and will work with any camera you're using.

Comment: @Blrfl, i thought about it, but that would be my last option! This could   lead to disassociated images due to bar codes not able to be read for any given situation. I Guess so far, its my best option!

Comment: you received some clear answer to the question? I'm also need a DSLR camera with a barcode scanner

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with pretty much any camera.  All you need to do is make sure the clock is synchronised with your barcode scanning tool, ideally at the beginning of each shooting session.

The only extra device you'll need will be something to scan the barcode.  A phone app is the most obvious option since you're likely to have that with you but it may take up too much time.  Something like an Opticon OPN-2001 barcode scanner would be quicker (and is small enough to be attached to the camera strap to keep images and metadata together.)  With both those options you'll know straight away if the code could not be read so shouldn't have any data loss issues.

After that it's a bit of simple scripting to merge the barcode data into the images back at 'base' or you may find an existing package to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve a custom DIY solution by using something like a Raspberry Pi.

You can attach the Raspberry Pi to a barcode reader. When the Pi scans the barcode it will query its database for the relevant MetaData information. You can then use Gphoto2 to query your camera via a USB cable and retrieve photos taken after the barcode was scanned. A simple batch script can then change the photos MetaData to match the one retrieved from scanning the barcode.

Some websites that might help: 
 http://photohacks.net/2014/09/11/setting-up-gphoto2-on-raspberry-pi/
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=67581&p=493805